# Django UnitTest with multiple databases

Tags: django

I have a Django project that has 2 database connections, one is the normal default connection and the other one taps into a legacy database.

And one of the apps have a migration like this:

```
def remove_dash_from_uuids(apps, schema_editor):
    Job = apps.get_model('task_manager', 'Job')

    for job in Job.objects.all():   
        job.uuid = str(job.uuid).replace('-', '')
        job.save()             


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('task_manager', '0003_default_enviroment'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(remove_dash_from_uuids),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='job',
            name='next_runs_hash',          
        ),
    ]
```

So this runs some custom code then remove the `next_runs_hash` field.

When I run the unit test, it created 2 test databases, one for "default" and one for "legacy", migrations applied successfully on "default" but fails on "legacy" saying `next_runs_hash` column does not exist.

I have verified that the `next_runs_hash` column does exist on `test_legacy` database.

What this is suggesting is that the `remove_dash_from_uuids` in the migration is run at the `default` connection, which should have been sticky to `legacy` connection.

So here are my questions:

1. How to make the `remove_dash_from_uuids` function to stick to the connection during migration on unit test.
2. Is there a way to avoid test database to be created for `legacy` connection?